# Add a vertical scrollbar to a wxFrame accross multiple wxPanels

Tags: python, wxpython, scrollbar, gnuradio

I want a vertical scrollbar **throughout** the frame (Top Block). I am able to get vertical scrollbars for the individual panels -

[image: Top Block]

Here both the plots are [threads](https://github.com/a-w-s/GNURadio-SBHS-Python/blob/master/python/plot_sink.py) plotted by the same [class](https://github.com/a-w-s/GNURadio-SBHS-Python/blob/master/python/matplotsink.py).

Here is the code which sets up the `top block` in *gnuradio* -

```
class top_block_gui(gr.top_block):
    def __init__(self, title='', size=default_gui_size):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self)
        .............
        self._frame = wx.Frame(None, title=title)
        self._panel = panel.Panel(self._frame)
        .............
    def Run(self, start=True, max_nouts=0):
        #setup app
        self._frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, _quit)
        self._sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self._sizer.Add(self._panel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self._frame.SetSizerAndFit(self._sizer)
        self._frame.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self._frame.Show(True)
        self._app.SetTopWindow(self._frame)
        #start flow graph
        ..................
```

**Edit 1 -** As suggested in *Method 1* by *pss* -

```
class top_block_gui(gr.top_block):
    def __init__(self, title='', size=default_gui_size):
        gr.top_block.__init__(self)
        .............
        self._frame = wx.Frame(None, title=title)
        self._scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self._frame,-1) #Added
        self._scroll.SetScrollbars(1,1,600,400) #Added
        self._panel = panel.Panel(self._scroll) #Changed
        .............
    def Run(self, start=True, max_nouts=0):
        #setup app
        self._frame.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, _quit)
        self._sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self._sizer.Add(self._panel, 0, wx.EXPAND)
        self._scroll.SetSizerAndFit(self._sizer) #Changed
        self._frame.SetAutoLayout(True)
        self._frame.Show(True)
        self._app.SetTopWindow(self._frame)
        #start flow graph
        ..................
```

But I still get the same results as before. **No scrollbar appears**. Do I have to set its *visibility true* somewhere by any chance?

Comment: Perhaps instead of adding the elements to panel itself, try creating a sizer, add the elements to it and then set this sizer on a panel.

Comment: Try `self._panel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self._scroll)` Also try resizing the frame manually to see if scroll bar appears. Sometimes they only appear when the frame is resized to a particular size or less than that size.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It finally worked. I had to change these lines in code under  **edit 1** - 
`self._scroll.SetSizer(self._sizer)`

`self._frame.SetAutoLayout(False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of the following ways to do so:

**Method 1:** You can use [wx.ScrolledWindow](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.ScrolledWindow-class.html)

Example code:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test app v1.0", style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE )
        self.Center()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.scroll = wx.ScrolledWindow(self, -1)
        self.scroll.SetScrollbars(1, 1, 600, 400)
        panelA = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.scroll, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, size=(300,200))
        panelA.SetupScrolling()
        panelA.SetBackgroundColour('#EEE111')
        panelB = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self.scroll, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, size=(200,200))
        panelB.SetupScrolling()
        panelB.SetBackgroundColour('#Eaa222')
        mainSizer.Add(panelA, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(panelB, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.scroll.SetSizer(mainSizer)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = GUI().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Method 2:** You can use the [wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel-class.html)

Example:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.scrolledpanel

class GUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test app v1.0", style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE )
        self.Center()
        self.CreateStatusBar()
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainPanel = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(self, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, size=(400, 200))
        mainPanel.SetupScrolling()
        mainPanel.SetBackgroundColour('#00000')
        panelA = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, size=(300,200))
        panelA.SetupScrolling()
        panelA.SetBackgroundColour('#EEE111')
        panelB = wx.lib.scrolledpanel.ScrolledPanel(mainPanel, -1, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, size=(200,200))
        panelB.SetupScrolling()
        panelB.SetBackgroundColour('#Eaa222')
        mainSizer.Add(panelA, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainSizer.Add(panelB, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        mainPanel.SetSizer(mainSizer)

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = wx.App(0)
    frame = GUI().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Output**:

[image: Code output]